# web scraping google news

Tags: python, windows

I came across [the page](http://mpand.github.io/gnp/). I want to install the package that the page has mentioned. I followed below steps from my windows command prompt. I updated pip as shown below. How could i install gnp?

```
C:\windows\system32>pip install gnp
Collecting gnp
  Using cached gnp-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2vb0ngae\gnp\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        long_description = file.read()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4894: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2vb0ngae\gnp\
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\windows\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |################################| 1.2MB 571kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.0
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.0
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1

C:\windows\system32>pip install gnp
Collecting gnp
  Using cached gnp-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6mm1sf6o\gnp\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        long_description = file.read()
      File "c:\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4894: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ng\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6mm1sf6o\gnp\
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's against Google's TOS to scrape their pages. Your IP will get blocked very quickly.

Comment: This looks like python3 issue. Can you try the same on 2.X ? I tried installing gnp on 2.7 and it works fine.

Comment: @Manuel it works. It seems that you are the owner of the page that i have referred. I need a bit more help. For example I want to search for "earth day" (i want earth day to be a single phrase and not 2 different words) and I also want to filter results for the last 365 days. Would you be able to help? Should i post a new question?

Comment: @user2543622 You can call this as `gnp.get_google_news_query('"Earth Day"')` so that its quoted. Also the pip version still uses `urllib2` which is depricated. You can download from my [github](https://github.com/mPAND/gnp) for latest version. Additional days filter would require to expand the functionality of package. Also you can provide the solution for the current SO question

Comment: @Manuel i looked at your github and i have added a new question. Please answer it if possible. You can put your first comment as an answer and i will approve it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874429/python-web-scraping-gnp-package